# Is it possible to drop "do" to make the sentence parallel

Tags: verbs, do-support, parallelism

Can I remove "do" from the below sentence? Does the meaning change?

> **Original:** In a recent survey, Physical Fitness Weekly found that people exercising daily consider themselves no healthier **than *do* people** exercising three to five times a week.

**EDIT:** Can I delete "do" and rephrase the sentence as the following.

> **Corrected:** In a recent survey, Physical Fitness Weekly found that people exercising daily consider themselves no healthier **than people** exercising three to five times a week.

Comment: Can you show us the source of the original sentence and tell us who marked it corrected? Is it from the same book?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you remove *do* the meaning changes.

Both versions are talking about two groups of people:

1. Those who exercise daily
2. Those who exercise 3-5 times a week.

The original sentence has only one meaning: it is comparing how people in group 1 feel about themselves with how people in group 2 feel about themselves.

The "corrected" sentence is ambiguous: it has two possible interpretations. One interpretation is the same as the original sentence - that interpretation isn't quite right without *do*, but some people would take it that way. The other (and in my opinion more likely) interpretation is that people in group 1 are comparing themselves with people in group 2 (where people in group 2 were not asked for an opinion).

Comment: @Rathony - I think the first sentence is fine. It's not an uncommon construction. *Than do people* is equivalent to *than people do*. Some other examples in [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104851/than-do-i-vs-than-i-do).

Comment: @Rathony - In the original it is quite clear exactly what is being compared: how people exercising daily consider themselves is compared with how people exercising 3-5 times/week consider themselves.

Comment: @nnnnnn I understand your answer. Can you please provide some correct and incorrect usage, as examples, of inversion in your main answer? So that I can accept your answer

Comment: A real sentence in the wild: *People in small towns and rural areas, he found, consider themselves no happier than do people living in big cities.* "[The Big City Has No Corner on Mental Illness](http://www.timhackler.com/big_city.html)" by Tim Hackler, The New York Times Magazine December 16, 1979.

Comment: Hmm... in my opinion, they are structurally identical. (FWIW, I'm okay with all these examples, but I don't think the corrected sentence given in the original post is a good correction.) It's a bit surprising to see that you're okay with *healthy/healthier* but not *happy/happier*.

Comment: In your case, it's the interpretation #2 in nnnnnn's answer. It's your opinion alone, not yours and your friend's in a survey or something. I think nnnnnn made this point clear enough in the answer.

Comment: @Rathony Actually, I was thinking of something like, on the scale of 1-10, 10 is the happiest, how happy are you? Not that I really know how they designed their research, though. Just try to help you think of something a bit more plausible for you.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Now I am clear. Corrected sentence is done by me; I thought it is correct.